# Seven Part Exhibit

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

[image: 7 cryptic clues positioned into a digital 8 shape]

What word is displayed by these seven clues?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The clue answers are:

> LINGERS, AGNES, REALIST, ERASING, ERG, STEALING, RESIGN:
>  [image: 7-segment display with clues answered]

Now,

> if we look at all the answers with an A in them, they trace out a number 4! Similarly, the `I` answers trace out a 3...
>
>  In fact, every letter traces a unique digit from 1 to 9. Ordered by this digit, the letters spell out **TRIANGLES**.

Comment: Wow, this is such a cool puzzle! (and cool answer too Deusovi)